# display strikethrough data in java server faces

Tags: java, jsf

I display a table of values contained in a list of Data objects

```
 <p:dataTable var="mydata" value="#{myBean.datas}>
```

In each Data object, I have a boolean attribute **isStrikethrough**.

I would like that, when the value **isStrikethrough** is set to true, the corresponding line should be strikethrough.

Could you provide me with some hints ?

Comment: by crossed you mean http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strikethrough ?

Comment: yes exactly thanks for the precision, I am not a native speaker

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it by this way also,

```
 <p:dataTable var="mydata" value="#{myBean.datas}>
      <rich:column styleClass="#{mydata.isStrikethrough ? 'strikeClass' : 'normalTextClass'}">
 </p:dataTable>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<p>
<ui:fragment rendered="#{mydata.crossed}">
<strike>Crossed Text</strike>
</ui:fragment>
<ui:fragment rendered="#{!mydata.crossed}">
Normal Text
</ui:fragment>
</p>
```

Comment: As `<strike>` is [deprecated in HTML 5](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_strike.asp) you could use `<del>` instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot,but is there a way not to duplicate the data, because it was a simplified example, and I have a lot of stuff ?

Comment: Build two separate fragments for `<strike>` and `</strike>`.